# Algorithm for straightening tilted document

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, ocr, document

I'm on a project involving OCR. After detecting each character, I need to combine close characters to create words. To do that I tried to create a priority queue, containing information about detected characters (the set of pixels forming the character and the position of the character on the document image), and gave higher priority to characters on top of the document, and higher to the leftmost character if two characters are on the same line. Then poll the characters out of the priority queue one after another, hoping that it would give me all the characters form left to right and up to bottom, and build words based on space between each two consequent characters. Which actually failed when the document is even slightly tilted, since some characters who are obviously on the same line for human eye are not necessarily on the same pixel height (with 5~10px threshold).

Is there any algorithm for autostraightening the document? or detecting the tilt angle? Or any library for that? Or if not, is there a way to work around this issue? It's my final year project and I have a very less time to fix this. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Which OCR engine do you use?

Comment: @ipoteka - none, I should train a neural network to recognize characters and then used that network for recognizing characters on document. I use Encog to implement a backpropagation Neural Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the skew and interline spacing are such that the text lines can always be separated by horizontals, it suffices to sort using a special comparison rule:

- if the bottom of A is above the top of B, then A precedes B, and conversely;
- else if some point in A is to the left of some point in B, then A precedes B, and conversely.

If the skew is too large, you will need to isolate the individual lines. A way  is to find the close left/right neighbors of every character, and form chains. Characters in a chain are sorted by abscissa.

When the skew is very large and the interline tiny, I know of no easy and bulletproof solution.

Comment: Great, I thought about this too this evening, but wasn't sure if it's the best I can do. Alright, I'll go with this and see the result tomorrow.

Comment: My best advice: don't use Fourier.

Comment: don't worry, your solution worked. Thanks. The tilt wasn't that harsh. The top of the character on the other end of the line stays above the bottom of the character on the one end. All I had to do was to change the if condition in the priority queue's comparator and everything is now working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe 2D Fourier Transform can help here:

1. smooth the document with radius comparable to character size
2. perform Fourier Transform
3. analyse spectrum

I would expect strong components to correspond to vertical direction and weaker components - to the horizontal. Also knowing line distance could limit area of analysis and improve accuracy.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but my knowledge of Fourier Transform is very limited (I wanted to use it early on in this project for some image pre-processing and was ready to learn it, but then I found a easier way so I let down the Fourier Transform). Maybe I'll try to find a quick walk-through Fourier Transform again if Yves' solution doesn't work. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Here's the one I use - http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/